# How to Configure AutoMapper Attributes in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, automapper

According to the [GitHUb](https://github.com/schneidenbach/AutoMapper.Attributes) documentation, To use ***AutoMapper.Attributes*** need three steps to be done as follows:

1. Create the classes you'd like to map.
2. Add the [MapsTo] attribute to the source class, with the destination type as the argument. (Alternatively, you can use the [MapsFrom] attribute to map the destination class with the source type.)
3. Call the MapTypes() extension method on the assembly from which you want to map your types.

**I have done the step 1 and step 2 but can not understand how to and where to use the step 3:**

Here is my Model classes:

```
[MapsFrom(typeof(ApplicationRole))]
public class RoleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

[MapsTo(typeof(RoleViewModel))]
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int, ApplicationUserRole>, IRole<int>
{
    public string Description  { get; set; }
}
```

And Here is my Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<ApplicationRole> applicationRoles = RoleManager.Roles.ToList();
    List<RoleViewModel> roleList = Mapper.Map<List<RoleViewModel>>(applicationRoles);  
    return View(roleList);
}
```

Would anybody tell me how to and where to Call the ***MapTypes()*** extension method on the assembly from which I want to map my types as suggested in step three of the ***AutoMapper.Attributes*** documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do in the Controller (eventually in the constructor):

```
 typeof(RoleViewModel).Assembly.MapTypes();
```

The problem can be solved if you install version 4 of Automapper because in the last version Attributes are not working. So please add the following instructions in Package-Manager Console:

```
uninstall-package Automapper

install-package Automapper -version 4.2.1
```

Comment: I did as the following: public RoleController()
        {
            typeof(RoleController).Assembly.MapTypes();
        } But did't work!! Throws exception as stating "
Sequence contains no matching element". Would you write the details code of the implementation please!!

Comment: @TanvirArjel please try with your `RoleViewModel` too. This error means that you are not mapping any types from Controller, so you should use it for the assembly you are mapping types. Sorry, I just assumed your types are in the same assembly.

Comment: Tried!! No solution yet!! Same exception throwing!! Moreover, My Types RoleViewModel and ApplicationRole are in different Assemblies.

Comment: @TanvirArjel you have used the `RoleViewModel` which has the `MapsFrom` attribute?

Comment: @TanvirArjel what do you mean by Assemblies? If both `ApplicationRole` and `RoleViewModel` are in different assemblies, how can they see each other?

Comment: @TanvirArjel assemblies does not mean .cs files, they means different dll/exe files.

Comment: @TanvirArjel I have corrected the answer, so it will solve your problem now

Comment: Finally It works...Thanks a lot..By the way, Where the dll/exe come from?? It is compiled output of the cs file..Isn't it??

Comment: @TanvirArjel it is the output of the hole project, with all the .cs files it contains, so all of your classes inside of a project are called an assembly! don't forget to mark as answer :)

Comment: Cannot mark as answer as I have less than 15 reputations!! Give a up vote to my question then I shall be able to mark your answer as useful with a up vote!!